# Django: Reference Database Entry

Tags: python, django

I wanna set to the user a background profile image. But instead of letting him place any image, I'll give some pics to let him choose. So I first was storing the images URLs in the Django code, and insert them directly into the database. But I think is more practical to store in a database all the images urls I want with their name, and then reference back into the database the image name.

So I have:

```
class BackgroundImage(models.Model):
    url = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    bgpic = <here it goes the code>
```

How can I reference a database entry of this model into my user URL profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to add a [foreign key reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) on the `User` table to the `BackgroundImage` table

```
class BackgroundImage(models.Model):
    url = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    bgpic = models.ForeignKey(BackgroundImage)
```

Then you will be able to set a references and access the values of the row attached via foreign key:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)

# set the fk reference
user.bgpic = BackgroundImage.objects.get(id=2)
user.save()

# access the reference  
print user.bgpic.url
print user.bgpic.name
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect. You helped me a lot to understand that.